# How can I close the main GUI in Java SE?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Using swing, I want to close my mainGUI with "setVisible(false)", how can I close it when I opened it like this:

```
public void run() {
     new mainGUI().setVisible(true);
}
```

I want to close the GUI from a method like this:

```
public void close(){
     //Close GUI here
}
```

What call is missing from my code to let the GUI close itself?

Comment: You need to store it in a field.

Comment: Note that `setVisible` doesn't "close", it simply hides.

Comment: dispose method, I think do your job.

Comment: You shoul metion, wha framework you use: Swing, SWT or AWT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends the place you wanna do that:

1. In the same class

   // Close the window

   this.detach();

or

```
// Hide the window
this.setVisible(false);
```

2. In other class you need to send the window like a param and use the same methods.

   // Close the window

   window.detach();

or

```
// Hide the window
window.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to close the GUI from a method like this:

Presumably you invoke this method when the user clicks on a button or menu item. So the best way is to create an `Action` that you add to the component. Then the `Action` will be executed when the component is clicked.

For example you can use the `Exit Action` found in [Closing An Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). The `ExitAction` will find the current window with focus and then close it.

Answer (score -1):

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) or you could use focus listener 
[image]

Go through this in java docs this might help you